# Which resistor should I add in place of potentiometer in XL6009 boost converter module to increase 3.7 V to 12 V?

Tags: resistors, boost, potentiometer, converter

I'm using 18650 batteries with XL6009 boost converter module to increase 3.7 V to 12 V. There is a potentiometer to control the output voltage in boost converter. But can we fix the output voltage to 12 V using resistor in place of potentiometer?

Comment: with two of them. dial it to 12v, remove pot, measure each half to determine resistor sizes.

Comment: I don't have a multimeter. So, is there anyway to use a fixed resistor?

Comment: well you could estimate by dialing the pot all the way to one side, then count the rotations to get to the other end stop. then count the rotations to get to 12v. (# of 12v turns / all turns) * pot total resistance = ohms. use total - that value to calc the other side.

Comment: XL6009 is a chip. It has no potentiometer. If you mean a product like a complete module, please mention which product it is. If it does not come with schematics you need to reverse-engineer how the potentiometer is connected to the chip to set the voltage. The XL6009 chip datasheet will provide a formula how to set the voltage with resistors.

Comment: With no multimeter, how do you even know you have reached 12 V output?

Comment: winny, I will surely borrow from someone though. I just asked that can we find the output without multimeter...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [datasheetspdf.com](https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/775384/XLSEMI/XL6009/1) the feedback pin of the XL6009 works at 1.25V

so you'll need a pair of resistors that can make 1.25V from 12V

so from the hole for the middle pot pin 1K to 0V and 8.6K (from the same starting place) to the output voltage.

Comment: I'll try that. Thank you.